# Configuring JmsToolBox for JBoss EAP 6.3 (HornetQ 2.3.x)

Tags: jboss, queue, jms, hornetq

[JMSToolBox](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox/?source=navbar) is a tool for browsing queues in a jms provider.

But it's not possible to configure it for browsing in JBoss EAP 6.3 (HornetQ 2.3).

Anyone tried this and can provide the right configuration?

Thanks in advance,
Mario

---

Update 2017-02-28:

With the help of the JTB author everything works now.

1. There was a problem in the version of JTB i used. This was fixed with JTB 3.8. The problem was that the bundled hornetq clients (version 2.4.x) had a problem with connecting to older versioned hornetq servers (version 2.3.x). This seemd to be a known bug.
2. The user/role used for the connection has to have the permission "manage".

@titou10: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of [JMSToolbox](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox).

JTB should work with HornetQ. At least it does on my test workstation.

Did you follow the [instructions to setup JMSToolBox for HornetQ](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox/wiki/2.7-Setup-for-JBOss-HornetQ)?

What exact problem do you encounter?

Comment: Sorry, it's a long time ago I've asked. I got this error message when trying to connect (tried port 5445 and 4447): HornetQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=HQ119013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]

Comment: What version of JMSToolBox are you using? is there a netty acceptor started on the ports you tried? is there a firewall beween the machine JTB is installed and the HQ server on this port? Setung instruction is here :https://sourceforge.net/p/jmstoolbox/wiki/Setup%20for%20JBoss%20HornetQ/

Comment: Mario, the problem is due to an imcopatibility between HornetQ v2.4.x jars bundled with JMSToolBox and HornetQ v2.3.x embedded with JBoss. JMSToolBox v3.8.0 will have a fix for the problem. check [this bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/jmstoolbox/bugs/9)

Comment: I tried again with JTB 3.9.0 Now it's trying to connect but i got the error message, that the specified user is not allowed for the permission=MANAGE. I don't know this permission, there are just the permission send, consume, createDurableQueue, deleteDurableQueue, createNonDurableQueue and deleteNonDurableQueue to configure in the hornetq server (embedded in JBoss EAP 6.3).

Comment: Mario, yes, the user must have the "manage" authority. It is explained in the JMSToolBox WiKi page on how to configure HornetQ for JMSToolBox here: https://sourceforge.net/p/jmstoolbox/wiki/Setup%20for%20JBoss%20HornetQ/

Comment: The project moved to GitHub (https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox). If I understood well, the Wiki page @titou10 is refering to is now here: https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox/wiki/2.7-Setup-for-JBOss-HornetQ

For the record, in order to add the required "manage" permission for HornetQ, edit your hornetq-configuration.xml then add the following lines in your security settings:

<security-setting match="jms.queue.hornetq.management">
  <permission type="manage" roles="admin" />
</security-setting>